# HTML output tag putting on wrong line

Tags: html, css

I wrote a little test form to see how the output tag works in html. Here is my form.

```
<form onsubmit="return false" oninput="d.value = (a.valueAsNumber + b.valueAsNumber + c.valueAsNumber)">
  <legend>Test</legend>

  <p><label for="a">Enter A:</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="a" value=0 name="a"></p>

  <p><label for="b">Enter B:</label>
  <input type="number" min="0" id="b" value=0 name="b"></p>

  <p><label for="c">Enter C:</label> 
  <input type="number" min="0" id="c" value=0 name="c"></p>

  <p>Sum: <strong><output name="d" for="a b c">0</output></strong></p>
</form>
```

But I am not getting the output in the form that I am expecting. This is what I see when I run the code through my test website. (Granted, formatting won't copy over.)

```
Test
Enter A:  3

Enter B:  4

Enter C:  5

Sum: 
12
```

I would think the sum should show up on the same line as it's label, correct? Any ideas as to why it would print on a new line?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate this in Chrome v53. Do you have some styling which sets `strong` or `output` elements to display as blocks?

Comment: I actually have no styling set.

Comment: And it does it in both my chrome and firefox browsers.

Comment: What happens if you remove <strong></strong> tags? Same?

Comment: Ya, just tried that. Same result.

Comment: Created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n5rxkLu0/) with your code, looks fine to me. How does it look for you?

Comment: Looks okay to me as well. Tested on several browsers.

Comment: Can you post the entire html code for your test so we can see if there's anything else going on that could affect it?

Comment: @JohnKlakegg ya, looks good there. I wonder why none of my browsers will display it correctly though...

Comment: @jim0thy trains about to land. I can post it when I get to a real computer. The only other code that's there is the bootstrap cdn stuff though.

Comment: Try doing the CSS reset, jut for the sake of testing: http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/

Comment: That's what it is then. Bootstrap sets `output` to `display:block`. You'll need to override it in your own CSS.

Comment: Exactly as @jim0thy noticed. I didn't see you wrote "bootstrap"...

Comment: Seems like it is solved, however, a tip for the future would be to look at the element's Computed styles in developer tools in your browser. When you expand the properties you will see if it uses default user agent values or if it's value is set through some stylesheet :)

Comment: @jim0thy I've attempted to override the display block and change it to inline but it looks like from that point on it is set to inline. Is there a way to only set the style to inline temporarily for my output tags?

Comment: @jim0thy sorry for the dumb comment. I wasn't doing the style in the output tag itself. All has been fixed now. Thanks for all the help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap's CSS sets the style of `output` to `display:block`. You'll need to override it in your own CSS.

For example:

```
output {
    display: inline-block;
}
```